# position asp: hyperlink with CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

How do I position this at the top right corner of the page with CSS?

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLogout" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Logout.aspx" ImageUrl="~/images/LogoutButton.png" CssClass="LogoutButton"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: This really depends on how your page is structured. Can you post the code for the rest of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the outermost parent container such as a div also positioned using `style="position:absolute"` you would be able to achieve your goal using the following:

```
.LogoutButton{
    position:absolute;
    right:0%;          
    top:0%;
}
```

As an aside, you can always use `px` instead to get a more accurate positioning. ie. `right:5px` would move the hyperlink 5px away  from the right border; the same can be said for the top property.

Comment: is the parent div also positioned absolute as stated above?

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

You can use an absolute position, but i suggest you use a div that is on top in your `_Layout.cshtml (if you use Asp.Net Mvc with the Razor View Engine)` or your `Masterpage (if you use Asp.Net Webforms)`.

Here is the css solution.

#### Sample

```
.LogoutButton
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    // other stuff
}
```